# global variable and local variable confusion

Tags: c, global-variables

```
#include <stdio.h>
int g;
void afunc(int x)
{
     g = x; /* this sets the global to whatever x is */
}

int main(void)
{
     g = 10;    /* global g is now 10 */
    afunc(20); /* but this function will set it to 20 */
     printf("%d\n", g); /* so this will print "20" */

     return 0;
}
```

The output of printf is 20.
but the local variable g = 10, 
so why it is printing 20 instead of 10
does local variable has more scope than global variable ?

Comment: The actual comments in your code explain it. XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it doesn't appear that you actually declared a new variable.  You just referred to 
g = 10;

You didn't actually define a new variable, simply referenced a global one. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

> The output of printf is 20. but the local variable g = 10, so why it
>   is printing 20 instead of 10

You are not changing a local variable. Your line in `main`

```
g = 10;
```

is changing the global variable. Similarly the function call to `afunc` changes the global variable. Your entire program has just one variable `g` and that is the global one.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have a local variable called `g` in your example. Only a global one. So the output is expected.

If you want a local variable called `g`, try this:

```
int main(void)
{
     int g = 10;    /* local g, initialized with 10 */
     ...
```

With the above, you now have two distinct variables called `g`, one of them visible only in `main`.